# How Do I have a Utility Function that Either Delivers an Existing Logger OR Instantiate a New One?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm putting my "get logging" function in a general helper file so I can call it frequently across my application. My logger looks like this:

```
def setupLogger():
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "::%(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    )

    if not rootLogger.hasHandlers() :
        buffer = StringIO()
        bufferHandler = logging.StreamHandler(buffer)
        bufferHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        bufferHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        bufferHandler.set_name('buffer.logger')
        rootLogger.addHandler(bufferHandler)

        stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        stdout_handler.set_name('stdout.logger')
        rootLogger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

    return (rootLogger, buffer)
```

Then I can call `util.setupLogger()` from any function and get both a stdout logger and a buffer (so that I can see what's been logged previously to console). However, I need to do a singleton style function like this because I never know if the logger has already been instantiated.

Unfortunately, this fails because buffer is not instantiated on every call to setupLogger (returning null), I can't put initialization of the buffer OUTSIDE the hasHandlers() function (because that wipes the history), and I can't seem to pry out the buffer from logger.StreamHandlers so that I can hand it back.

I feel like I'm making this more complex than it needs to be, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about returning the stream inside the handler?

```
def setupLogger():
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "::%(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    )

    if not rootLogger.hasHandlers() :
        buffer = StringIO()
        bufferHandler = logging.StreamHandler(buffer)
        bufferHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        bufferHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        bufferHandler.set_name('buffer.logger')
        rootLogger.addHandler(bufferHandler)

        stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        stdout_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        stdout_handler.set_name('stdout.logger') # BTW here I found a typo, I have fixed it.
        rootLogger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

    buffer = rootLogger.handlers[0].stream

    return rootLogger, buffer
```